# Are there any ways i can take 1 letter from a word, and then mix that letter with another letters choosen from other words

Tags: python

Title is complicated yeah, but i will show an example what i want to achieve..

So i give a list of words

```
keywords = ['paper', 'car', 'plane', 'keys']
```

Then i take 1 or more letters from each of those words in the keywords list and mix them together in a 1 random word like this

```
word: pany
word: rpars
word: sprya
```

ofc i want to run this on a loop for like 100 times, but i need to get the general part done first

thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @DanielWalker Thank you for welcoming me. Ive already received the help i needed and learned from my mistakes what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking a question on Stack Overflow you should provide some example code of what you've tried and identify what specifically it is you need help with. Instead, you have basically asked us to write code for you. Be aware of this ediquete in the future.

That said I took the 15 minutes to write your code as I was looking for an easy brain teaser:

```
import random

keywords = ['paper', 'car', 'plane', 'keys']

#output random word however many times
for number in range(100):
    random_word = ''

    #Loop through keywords and generate random letters
    for word in keywords:
        #Determine how many letters we will grab
        letters_to_grab = random.randrange(1, len(word))

        #Grab a random letter for however many we need
        for letter in range(letters_to_grab):

            #Add random letter to word
            random_letter_index = random.randrange(1, len(word))
            random_word = random_word + word[random_letter_index]

            #remove picked letter from word
            word = word[:random_letter_index] + word[random_letter_index + 1:]

    print(random_word)
```

I think this code mostly explains itself, but ask questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Ive tried to code my own code for like 3hrs now and the start wasn't even working the way i wanted so i didn't even have anything i can provide and show, so i was trying my best to explain the thing i wanted to achieve.. Thank you for your time to write this code, i would give you +rep, but it doesn't allow me to.